# Aproximar a decimal SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, tsql, transact-sql

Deseo aproximar al decimal 0.5 mas cercano en SQL

Es decir:

2.3 que se aproxime a 2.5
2.8 que se aproxime a 3

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La opción más sencilla es multiplicar por 2, redondear a enteros y dividir entre 2. Dejo un ejemplo junto con los datos de prueba.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) /10. n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n, 
     ROUND( n * 2, 0) / 2 -- Esta linea es lo único que es necesita la solución. El resto es para mostrar datos de prueba.
FROM cteTally;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta esa era la solución

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, marcala como aceptada.